# Wordpress how to make current theme responsive

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a website and i have applied a WordPress theme to it. But it is not responsive and doesn't view properly on mobile and other handle held devices. So is there any way to make an existing applied theme responsive ?

I am using PAID THEME NOVA.

Is there is any steps which i need to follow ?

Thanks

Ankita

Comment: Any plugin may be, or a bit of css modification may be, a bit of R&D would give you your answer anyway. Check the following link as an example: https://www.maketecheasier.com/make-wordpress-site-responsive/ @Ankita Kashyap

Comment: if you are not an experienced web developer, might as well not touch it.. it's not that easy to do and you might break the site..

Answer (score 0):

Making a website responsive is not automatic. You need atleast to use [CSS Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to make your webpages responsive.

Though there are also responsive frameworks available out there, for example [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), which are brilliant to use if you want a highly responsive page, but I guess the learning curve is much harder than learning to use Media Queries.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin Jetpack has a module to add a mobile theme to your site. Read about it at https://jetpack.me/support/mobile-theme/. This is a stopgap solution if you can't or don't want to code. Making a theme properly responsive is a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

If the theme you are using is [this one](http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/nova/) update the theme to the latest version as it apparently already *is* responsive.

Contact the developers of your theme for specific steps you may need to take to 'enable' this option. If it is a paid theme then you are more than likely entitled to support.